# Restricting the file path in fileupload control asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, file-upload

I would like to restrict the file path to one particular folder.
User should be able to access only that folder.

Comment: I don't think it's possible because how would server will know the directory structure of user's computer?

Comment: what abt server side folders??

Answer (score 0):

User can't choose a folder on a server where file will be uploaded at least until a developer doesn't provide such possibility with additional functionality. It's absolutelly on you as an application developer where are files those users uploads on a server will be saved.